# Drag and Drop Issue TIBCO BusinessWorks 6.4

Tags: wsdl, tibco, tibco-business-works

I'm using TIBCO BusinessWorks 6.4 trial version and i have issue when i try to drag and drop a WSDL file into a process :

When i drag the file from the Service Descriptors Folder and try to drop it and click invoke operation for example, nothing is done.

Could anyone help me please ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved my case by creating a virtual machine with virtual box running under linux (Ubuntu 16.04) and i installed Tibco BW 6.4 and now it's working !

Answer (score 1):

I think your WSDL contains many interfaces. If yes, drag and drop the interface you want (by expanding the content of your wsdl in the services descriptors)

Comment: Hello  i've done so,but it is still not working it seems to be a bug.

Comment: @SANTEREK can u provide us a capture , when expending ur wsdl ?

Comment: It's a known issue, but we can work around it by dragging appropriate interface. as asked @FuSsA, can you provide the screenshot to analyze?

Comment: I solved my case by creating a virtual machine with virtual box running under linux (Ubuntu 16.04) and i installed Tibco BW 6.4 and now it's working !